# Can i decrement text in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have permalinks with numbers on the end like `example_3` and I want to decrement each in a mongoDb update ( i.e. `example_2`) but it's text.  Is there a way to do this?

```
posts.update(
        { 'title':doc.title, 'student':username, 'copy':false, 'class_number':{ '$gt': doc.class_number } }, 
        { '$inc': { 'class_number':-1, 'permalink':-1 } }, 
        { multi: true }, 
        function(err, dox){
                if (err) return callback(err, null);
            console.log('decclassnumber');
            console.log(dox + ' posts were decremented.');
            callback(err, dox);         
    });
```

Comment: Since MongoDB has no way of knowing what you want to decrement I would say no, you have to do this yourself

Comment: You can use `$set`, but not `$inc`.

Comment: @GergoErdosi Right I tried `$set` but each value would be different, so I would need to find each permalink, then pop it, minus 1 and then set it.  But how could I find each value during an update?

Comment: Please add sample data and the expected output. Also, if the numbers are supposed to be increased / decreased, it would be better to store them separately and construct the permalink in your application. That way you could easily use `$inc`.

Comment: You cannot, MongoDB for one does not yet support projection of the document in question and even then you would need some code to actually update it how you want to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to increment/decrement an alphanumeric string; you need to separate the original string value into meaningful parts before asking MongoDB (or your application code) to adjust the numeric portion.

Normally with [permalinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permalink) you would also be incrementing values rather than decrementing -- the whole intent of permalinks is to ensure that a given link is always pointing to the same resource.

It sounds like you actually want to implement a sequence pattern, where you find the next available sequence value to use.

For example, see: [Create an Auto-Incrementing Sequence](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) in the MongoDB manual.

Here's a slightly modified version of the `getNextSequence()` function in the documentation that uses `upsert` to either find an existing slug counter document or insert a new one. The return value is a new unique slug:

```
function getNextSequence(name) {
   var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
      {
        query: { _id: name },
        update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
        upsert: true,
        new: true,
      }
   );

    // Return the new slug (eg: "example_1")
    return name + '_' + ret.seq;
}

> getNextSequence("example")
example_1
> getNextSequence("example")
example_2
> getNextSequence("example")
example_3
```

If you do want to decrement from some starting value, you could insert a starting value for your sequence and reduce that instead with `$inc: { seq: -1 }`.